# Only Return random number which is not in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to make a function that takes an array as an argument, creates a random number from `1 - 10`, and runs until it creates a number that is not in the array, and returns it.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/an3ogr34/5/)

```js
function contains() {
  var check = false;
  while (!check) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    random += 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] === random) {
        console.log(random);
        check = false;
        return false;
      }
    }
    check = true;
    console.log(random);
    return true;
  }
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

$(".test").on("click", function() {
  contains(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="test">
Test
</button>
```

Comment: you should put a question rather than a statement instead

Answer (score 6):

Use the `.includes` Array method to see if a value exists in an array or not:

https://jsfiddle.net/an3ogr34/8/

```
function contains(arrParam) {
  while (true) {
    var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    if (!arrParam.includes(random)) return random;
  }
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
$(".test").on("click", function() {
  const result = contains(arr);
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie, not really, because the superfluous check on starting the loop and the use of an unnecessary variable.

Comment: @NinaScholz, what's unnecessary, what superfluousness? I did try to make the function purer, but I don't think that's a bad thing

Comment: *pure* in combination with function and random does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple mistakes

- `arr` that is being used by `contains` function is localized when you passed the same as an argument. **`contains` function is not able to access the global `arr`**
- You are returning both `true` and `false`, so even if the `random` item is included in the `arr`, **`contains` return from the function**.

Make it

```
function contains() {
  var check = false;
  while (!check) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    check = !arr.includes(random);
  }
  return random;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function contains() {
  var check = false;
  while (!check) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    check = !arr.includes(random);
  }
  return random;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

$(".test").on("click", function() {
  console.log(contains());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="test">
Test
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`do ... while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) loop, because you need at least one loop for checking the random number, and check with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for continuing the loop.

Don't forget to hand over the array for checking and use that array inside of the function.

```js
function contains(array) {
    var random;
    
    do {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    } while (array.includes(random))

    return random;
}

var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

console.log(contains(numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have proposed the solution with the use of `indexOf()`

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function contains() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  if (arr.indexOf(randomNumber) === -1) {
    return randomNumber;
  } else {
    console.log(`Number exists: ${randomNumber}`);
  }
}

$(".test").on("click", function() {
  var returnNumber = contains();
  if (!!returnNumber) {
    console.log(`Number not exists: ${returnNumber}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="test">
Test
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function contains(arr) {

    if(arr.length<10){
        while(true){
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            random += 1;

            if(!arr.includes(random)){
                return random;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

$(".test").on("click", function () {
    console.log(contains(arr));  //for print in console
    contains(arr);
});
```